# Sending "%" to an API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, urlencode, restful-url

In our RESTful API, we use RQL to parse URL-s and build query out of it. This is an example of a query:

`http://www.example.com/resource?resource.name~=%Some name%`

which translates to a `LIKE` operator.

Then, in our frontend, we implement a search field, of which change triggers an ajax request to:

`'http://www.example.com/resource?resource.name~=%' + query + '%'`

Of course, there is a bug - each special combination with "%" gets translated server-side to a character, resulting in query returning no results.

How to solve it?

I tried to `encodeURIComponent` the whole stuff after `?` but it gets even worse, for example `resource.name~%3D%25befr%25` which "befr" as query string.

I have no other ideas how to solve this issue.

Comment: What server-side bug are you facing? It's hard to find a solution to an unknown problem.

Comment: tip! use `<>` instead of `~=` and do you require to add or trim `%` ?

Comment: As I said: "each special combination with "%" gets translated server-side to a character, resulting in query returning no results.". For example, trying to search for something beginning with "b" turns to a URL containing `%b`, which is a special combination representing a character

Comment: you can trim on MYSQL end  `SELECT TRIM(BOTH '%' FROM 'query');`

Comment: @diEcho: No, we need them. It is a LIKE query. The question is already solved, thank you for your effort.

Comment: Alright, I was assuming you were trying to find a workaround for a buggy server. Rather than that, the server appears to do the right thing: handle % escape sequences as the URI specs mandate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The components of a query string are the key names and values.

```
?key=value&key=value
```

Don't encode the `=` characters. They aren't part of the component, they divide the components up.

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/resource?' +
    encodeURIComponent("resource.name~") +
    "=" + 
    encodeURIComponent("%" + query + "%");
```

Comment: Yes, incredible, but it was INDEED as easy as this.

Answer (score 3):

Try simply replacing % for its URLEncoded equivalent "%25"

Comment: You are right. However, I find the solution of @Quentin better, because it uses functions rather than hard-coded strings. But still plus one for this tip.

Comment: That works for this specific query (since it doesn't have any special characters in it) but is a poor approach in the general case.